# How to POST whole object using BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an index view that lists results of a SQL query that aggregates errors from a log table.

I have a "details" link for each of these aggregated records that will allow the user to drill into the details of each record.

The details view will then load more SQL data for this record.

Since there is no ID or key to look up by, I'm using the error string, which can sometime be very large and include "potentially dangerous characters" to pass in as the param.

Is there a better way to go about accomplishing this?

EDIT: I'm now storing the entire results set into the Session and selecting the correct row by it's index which I'm passing in. This is working but I would prefer to avoid session use in the case if possible.

Comment: Surely the log table has a primary key.  Why not include it in the details link?

Comment: This is a flattened version of the log table and the query is grouping by error which does not include any keys or ids.

Comment: Why not you generate a hash from the error string and use that as a primary key instead just for the viewmodel?

Comment: Is there a way for you to add you own unique id (guid perhaps) when querying and grouping the data by error message?

Comment: How about you provide the primary key from one of the rows in the SQL group by (e.g. use `MIN`)?  For retrieving the details, provide a stored procedure which accepts the ID and finds all rows that match the log text that goes with it, which will include but not be limited to the row with the matching ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick an ID from the underlying table and link it back somehow.  Here's the sketch of an example:

To retrieve the data for your HTML table:

```
SELECT MIN(LogTablePK) as ArbitraryId, LogText
FROM LogTable
GROUP BY LogText
```

To render the table:

```
<A HREF="GetDetails.cshtml?ID={ArbitraryId}">{LogText}</A>
```

To obtain details:

```
SELECT * FROM LogTable
WHERE LogText = (SELECT LogText FROM LogTable WHERE LogTablePK = {ArbitraryId})
```